# IntelliJ plugin for cucumber-scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, cucumber, sbt

I am running Cucumber scala project in IntelliJ

```
IntelliJ IDEA - 13.0.2
```

I couldn't find separate plugin called cucumber for scala

In my project I am getting `cannot resolve` message for cucumber as below

[image]

Could see below errors as well

[image]

Existing plugins installed

[image]

What could be the solution

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You are missing dependencies for cucumber-core and cucumber-scala, please have a look at the [documentation](http://cukes.info/install-cucumber-jvm.html) and add them to your build.sbt file.

Update:
There is a newer version available for sbt-cucumber-plugin (0.8.0): https://github.com/skipoleschris/xsbt-cucumber-plugin. Maybe that solves your problems.

Did you try the [gen-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) plugin to create the IntelliJ IDEA project files ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. BTW why I can't find `cucumber-scala` plugin by the name under the `Browse Repository` in IntelliJ. Or is it in different name

Comment: Anyway I had `addSbtPlugin("templemore" % "sbt-cucumber-plugin" % "0.7.2")` line in `plugins.sbt` file

Comment: Please let me know how to include `https://github.com/skipoleschris/xsbt-cucumber-plugin` in the `plugin.sbt` file. I tried `resolvers += "Templemore Repository" at "http://templemore.co.uk/repo/"

addSbtPlugin("templemore" % "sbt-cucumber-plugin" % "0.8.0")` as I could see the repo there. But I am getting `[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/templemore/sbt-cucumber-plugin_2.9.2_0.12/0.8.0/sbt-cucumber-plugin-0.8.0.pom` error because that location is not exist. But not sure where it pickup that location

Comment: and underneath this error `[warn]  
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  :: templemore#sbt-cucumber-plugin;0.8.0: not found
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]   templemore:sbt-cucumber-plugin:0.8.0 (sbtVersion=0.12, scalaVersion=2.9.2)
[warn] sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: templemore#sbt-cucumber-plugin;0.8.0: not found at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:214)`

Comment: I am currently using `$ sbt --version
sbt launcher version 0.13.2
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: D:\sbt\bin\sbt-launch.jar
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/d/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
sbt launcher version 0.13.2`

Comment: I had above for machine SBT installation. I think that doesn't care. Then I updated `build.properties` to `sbt.version=0.13.0`. Then there were no errors while import. But still `scala` objects seeing `Cannot resolve` message

Comment: name := "Your project name"

version := "1.0"




scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.detro.ghostdriver" % "phantomjsdriver" % "1.1.0",
  "org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-java" % "2.43.0",
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.1",
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.11.2",
  "info.cukes" % "cucumber-scala_2.11" % "1.1.8",
  "info.cukes" % "cucumber-junit" % "1.1.8",
  "info.cukes" % "cucumber-picocontainer" % "1.1.8",
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.11" % "test",
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.10" % "test"
)

Comment: the above code should be added to sbt file so that you can run the tests in scala with cucumber in intellij.